# Problems when using unordered_set as the key of unordered_map, in C++

Tags: c++, boost, hash, containers, unordered

The original problem is kind of long, so I simplify it here.

I need to create a group of strings, with a relevent integer, let's say a training group. Then I need to create many training groups. I want to manage all the training groups in a single container. So I decided to use boost::unordered_map<> with the key being std::unordered_set. Because, the BOOST has hash value for the standard C++ container.

The simplified code are as follows:

```
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <utility>
#include<boost/unordered_map.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    boost::unordered_map< unordered_set<string>, int> training_groups;
    pair<unordered_set<string>, int> a_training_group;
    training_groups.insert(a_training_group);
    return 0;
}
```

However, the code doesn't compile successfully. There are many cryptic warnings and an error. The error is as follows:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xhash(30): error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'const std::unordered_set<std::string,std::hash<_Kty>,std::equal_to<_Kty>,std::allocator<_Kty>>' to 'size_t'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=std::string
1>          ]
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
1>          C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_59_0\boost/functional/hash/extensions.hpp(262) : see reference to function template instantiation 'size_t stdext::hash_value<T>(const _Kty &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=std::unordered_set<std::string,std::hash<std::string>,std::equal_to<std::string>,std::allocator<std::string>>
1>  ,            _Kty=std::unordered_set<std::string,std::hash<std::string>,std::equal_to<std::string>,std::allocator<std::string>>
1>          ]
```

I don't know where is the origin of this error and how to solve it. If the compiler cannot file the hash function of unordered_set, the error information will contains words like "Hash" or "Key". However, it just says something about type conversion, which looks similar to hash function. So, I feel confused.

Can anyone provide some advice. I am using Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 8.

PS: when I changed the Key `unordered_set<string>` to `set<string>` or `vector<string>`, the program compiles successfully. But I still don't know the reason, and don't know how to solve the problem if I am determined to use `unordered_set<string>` as the key.

Comment: why do you think must the set be the key of the map?

Comment: For my real problem, the second part of a training group is actually another unordered_set<> of self-defined type. In this post, I use an integer to simplify the question. So, compared with unordered_set<> of self-defined type, an unordered_set<> of string is better to be used as Key.

Also, I can change the Key unordered_set<> to just set<> or vector<>. However, the unordered_set<> is more convenient and faster for future manipulations.

Comment: @JohnSmith: Using an `unordered_set` as a key is really not very fast, since the comparison predicate is really slow. It can be quadratic in the set size (precisely because the collection is unordered).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boost does **not** provide a hash function for `std::unordered_set`, the list of hash functions contains e.g. one for `std::set`:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/hash/reference.html#idp6283424-bb

So you must provide your own hash function, which is relatively easy when using `boost::hash_range`:

```
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <utility>
#include <boost/functional/hash/hash_fwd.hpp>

namespace boost
{
template <class K, class C, class A>
std::size_t hash_value(const std::unordered_set<K, C, A>& v)
{
    return boost::hash_range(v.begin(), v.end());
}
} // namespace boost

#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>
#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>
int main()
{
    boost::unordered_map<std::unordered_set<std::string>, int> training_groups;
    std::pair<std::unordered_set<std::string>, int> a_training_group;
    training_groups.insert(a_training_group);
    return 0;
}
```

<kbd>[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8f02914cccd4f7fe)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you very much. I missed that BOOST does not provide a hash function for std::unordered_set.    By the way, is std::unordered_set being considered as a standard C++ container?

Comment: Yes it's easy to provide a hash function for std::unordered_set. A hash function that works is a bit more tricky. Why do you think boost doesn't provide one? Hint: the page you've linked says why.

Comment: @JohnSmith: [`std::unordered_set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) is part of the C++ standard library since C++11.

Comment: One challenge you might run into, and I don't know the details of boost::hash_range, but if the iteration order matters for that hash function, then it's possible that two equivalent sets actually end up with different hash values. From a quick check of the docs, it doesn't look order agnostic.